# Mouse hover text to be logged in report (Selenium)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I want to get the text from mouse hover on an element on a webpage and put it in log. I tried `getText` and `getValue` but they are not working.

I am using Selenium and robotframework.

I want to get:

`This property can be modified in dt-site.xml located in the user home directory`

from:

`<i ng-if="!row.canSet" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign ng-scope" tooltip-popup-delay="0" tooltip-placement="left" uib-tooltip="This property can be modified in dt-site.xml located in the user home directory."></i>`

Comment: Post the page source with the element

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is coming from the tooltip.  You can try this:

```
String title = webElement.getAttribute("uib-tooltip");
```

If this does not work, then it could be because of angular magic.  Tryu

```
String title = webElement.getAttribute("title");
```

The `title` attribute is what the browser reserves as the "popup" text.

Comment: To add on the correct answer - in robotframework the keyword to use is `${popup}=     Get Attribute Value    ${your_locator}@uib-tooltip` . The ${your_locator} is the id/css/xpath of the element, and the part after the @ is the actual html element's attribute name